# Permissions over script in a directory

Tags: bash, permissions

Maybe this is for dummies, but i'm not sure. My directory has the permissions:

```
drwx------ 2 root   root 4096 oct 16 11:39 scripts
```

But the script have the permissions:

```
-rwxrwxrwx  1 user user   39 oct 16 17:32 script.sh
```

But when i try to execute the script i get

```
bash: script.sh: Permission denied
```

I don't understand what is happening, because user can't execute the script (the owner and group were changed manualy) and obviusly root can.

Comment: Are you trying to run the script as 'user' or as 'root'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user doesn't have permission to access the directory, or use it as part of a path.  That's what the execute bit on directories means.

If you were to `chmod o+x scripts` then the user would be able to use scripts in that directory, but could not create new things in it or get a directory listing (that requires the read bit).

Comment: And only changing the x bit will be enough??? No need to change the group of the folder???

Comment: Right, the user isn't part of the `root` group (I assume) so the group permissions wouldn't matter

Comment: Though actually, the `chmod` I gave would also change the group, I should have said `chmod o+x` not `a+x` so I'll fix that, though it probably doesn't make much difference really

Comment: The a+x made the trick, but i think o+x is more especific. So, to finally understand, the complete path need to have the x bit? Each part (directory) of the path?

Comment: Right, to include a directory in a path you're using (for any purpose) you must have execute permissions on it.  So that ends up being the case for each part of the path, you have to have execute on every directory or you can't use it